# Automated chemistry test machines? What is currently done, and what is research leaning towards?

Tags: reaction-mechanism, experimental-chemistry, equipment

There are small and large chips and machines to effect admixtures,blends, fusions of different chemicals into a variety of test samples, and there are machines to measure many vials of all kinds of biological and synthetic compounds.

The challenge is that there are so many ways to synthesize materials, using pressure, condensation, temperature, phase change onto centrifugal plate, and 100ds of other synthesis methods, lasers, using for example 40 interesting materials, there are too many possibilities for an unlimited number of machines for synthesis, the topic is unfathomable from the very start.

If we take 40 chemicals, we have billions of possible experiments to do with them, it makes the concept of fast robotic chemistry labs suitable for the synthesis and measurement of many exotic materials, and it's a very confusing topic.

What work has been done with automated chemistry synthesis and testing machines, and what will they be able to do in the next 10 or 20 years?

Are any automated test machines used to test the result of an automated compound creation machine?

Are there presently automated R&D labs that mass produce random combinations of materials in the constant search for new useful discoveries, can you shine some light on some research in the subject?

Comment: I found some info on the subject after changing the wording of the search:   --------> http://www.nature.com/news/organic-synthesis-the-robo-chemist-1.15661   and --------->http://science.sciencemag.org/content/347/6227/1221.full

Comment: ----> alot of results are here ----> https://www.google.fr/search?sourceid=chrome-psyapi2&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8&q=automated%20materials%20science%20synthesis&oq=automated%20materials%20science%20synthesis&aqs=chrome..69i57.7512j0j4